# Error deploying Mern Stack application on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment, mern

I am trying to deploy a full-stack app on heroku, i have tried couple of things but none of them worked... when i entered "heroku logs" to follow up with the errors it should me **code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND** even though the node_module's can be found in both the **Root** of the project and the **Frontend** file as well , how do i fix this error and where does it come from ?

[image]
**Here's a picture of my projects structure**:

[image]

**server.js:**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const productRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");



connectDB();

const app = express();


app.use(express.json());

//--------------- deployment -------
app.use("/api/products", productRoutes);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
    app.use(express.static(path.join('../frontend/build')));
  
    app.get('*',(req,res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'../frontend/build','index.html'))
    })
    
  } else {
    app.get("/", (req, res) => {
      res.send("Api running");
    })
  }

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

**.env:**

```
PORT=8080
MONGO_URI=*****
NODE_ENV=production
```

**Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "mern-shopping-build",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Shopping list built with MERN stack",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.4.1",
    "npm": "7.18.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd frontend && npm run dev",
    "install-client": "cd frontend && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
    "client": "npm start && cd frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm start --prefix frontend\""
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Karim ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.9"
  }
}
```

**ProcFile:**

```
web node server.js
```

I Would appreciate any kind of feedback or help, Thank you!

Comment: did you add a `buildpack` for the React app? See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks. Heroku does not provide a buildpack for React apps, so you'll need to use a 3rd party one, e.g. https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack

Answer (score 0):

A **Procfile** is not technically required to deploy simple apps written in most Heroku-supported languages—the platform automatically detects the language and creates a default web process type to boot the application server.

Just make sure to point your **root** `package.json` **main** key to **backend/server.js**.

Most likely it would work otherwise share your Build Logs to check it further.

```
{
   "main": "backend/server.js"
}
```